# Django Error: permission denied for relation django_admin_log

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I am trying to access the admin interface for my Django project. I can access the initial 'login' screen but, once I type in my credentials, I get the following error:

> ProgrammingError at /admin/
>
> permission denied for relation django_admin_log
>
> Exception Type: ProgrammingError
>
> Exception Value:
>   permission denied for relation django_admin_log
>
> Exception Location: .../.virtualenvs/testing/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute, line 65
>   Error during template rendering
>
> In template .../.virtualenvs/testing/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html, error at line 63
>
> permission denied for relation django_admin_log

I've barely written any code yet (finally finished setting up postgresql database), but something is amiss and I can't access the admin page.
My models are "registered" in admin.py and the app is included under INSTALLED APPS in settings.py. I have altered nothing in views.py or urls.py.

Any help would be very, very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you run the `manage.py syncdb`command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Database access denied error.

Check your Database server access settings.

In Postgresql for example (any change need server restart):

/etc/postgresql/X.X/main/pg_hba.conf

```
host    all   all   0.0.0.0    0.0.0.0   md5
```

Comment: I do have access to the database via the psql interactive shell. Does that matter? My pg_hba.conf looks like:

Comment: With what user? the same of your settings.py?

Comment: And that user is the owner of the database? I mean, you create the database with that user as owner?

Comment: That was it! The user was not the "owner." I switched it and it works. Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 0):

**This is an Database access denied error.**

If you are using Linux and have Postgres SQL installed, follow these steps:

**1. Switch over to the postgres account on your server(local machine) by typing**:

```sh
sudo -i -u postgres
```

**2. You can now access a Postgres prompt immediately by typing:**

```sh
psql
```

his will log you directly into Postgres and you prompt will look like this : *postgres=#*

**3. Delete django_admin_log table**

```sh
DROP TABLE django_admin_log;
```

**4. Create a new django_admin_log table**

```sh
CREATE TABLE django_session (
    id              integer,
    action_time     timestamp with time zone,
    object_id       text,
    object_repr     character varying(200),
    action_flag     smallint,
    change_message  text,
    content_type_id integer,
    user_id         integer
);
```

**5. Exit**

```sh
\q
```